# Don't Display the value

Tags: visualforce

Hi i have this simple code i just want to display values on vf Page but it shows nothing.Here is the Code

```
public with sharing class Additionoftwonum
   {
    public integer a{get; private set;}
    public integer b{get; private set;}
    public integer c{get; private set;}

    public Additionoftwonum()
    { 
       /* a = 10;
        b = 20;
        c=a+b; */
       sum(); //First call your method
    }
    public integer sum()
    {

        // a=10;
        // integer a = 10;
       integer a = 10;
        this.a = a;
        integer b =20;
        this.b = b;
        integer c;
        this.c = this.b+this.a;



        // b=20; 



         system.debug('The value is = ' +c);
         return 10;

    }

}
```

Here is Screenshot of Vf Page

[image]

Comment: or just call this method from `Page's action` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So when page load first constructor calls.. You need to call your method from constructor

If you declared your variable in above and again try to create a variable with same name then that will be overridden..example you did for variable a,b and c

Try this

```
<apex:page controller="Additionoftwonum">
    <apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:outputText value="{!a}"></apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText value="{!b}"></apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText value="{!c}"></apex:outputText>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Class

```
public with sharing class Additionoftwonum 
{
    public integer a{get; private set;}
    public integer b{get; private set;}
    public integer c{get; private set;}

    public Additionoftwonum ()
    {
       sum(); //First call your method
    }
    public void sum()
    {

         a=10;

         b=20; 

         c=a+b;

         system.debug('The value is' +c);

    }

}
```

Comment: Hello Ratan Still show nothing on vf page after adding Constructor.How it display value on vf page?

Comment: Hello did You Check on your developer console bcoz its show nothing after changing the code

Comment: @Bonny I have added page and controller in my ans check

Comment: Hello Ratan i Found the new way to do this Plz Check the Edit Code.

Comment: @Bonny nice one . Yes you do that way as well..